# C++0x: Capture By Value for Lambda, always a copy?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, lambda

Is the compiler allowed to **eliminate the copy** that is required for the *by-value capture*?

```
vector<Image> movie1;
apply( [=movie1](){ return movie1.size(); } );
```

- Is there any circumstance that the compiler does not need to copy `movie1`?

  - Maybe if the compiler could know, that `apply` does not actually *change* `movie1`?
  - Or does it help that Lambdas are by default *`const` functors* in any case?
- Does it help *at all* that `vector` has a *move constructor* and *move assign*?

  - If yes, is it required to add these to `Image` as well, to prevent an expensive copy here?
- Is there a difference in the mechanism when and how a copy is required for *by-value capture* compared to *by-value arguments*? eg. `void operate(vector<Image> movie)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm fairly sure it cannot.

Even if the outer function no longer explicitly uses the variable, moving the variable would change the semantics of destruction.

Having move constructors for `Image` doesn't help, a `vector` can `move` or `swap` without moving its elements.

If the variable is read-only from this point forward, why not capture by reference?  You could even create a const reference and capture that.

If the variable is not read-only, the copy is required.  It doesn't matter whether the outer function or the lambda performs the modification, the compiler cannot allow that modification to become visible to the other.

The only difference I see between *by-value capture* and *by-value argument passing* is that the capture is named, it cannot be a temporary.  So argument passing optimizations applicable to temporaries cannot be used.

Comment: "why not capture by reference"? I am in the process of understanding all implications. I agree. "The only difference..." is a great answer. Perfect!

Answer (score 3):

There is *always* the "as-if" rule. As long as it looks *as if* the rules had been followed, the compiler can do whatever it likes. So for objects where the copy constructor and destructor have no side effects, and where no changes are made to the copy, or the original object isn't accessed afterwards (so no one will notice if we make changes to the object), the compiler could prove that eliminating the copy is legal under the "as-if" rule.

But other than that, no, it can't just eliminate the copy, as @Ben said. The "regular" copy elision rules don't cover this case.

Comment: Thats the term I was looking for: *copy elision*. Thanks for clarify that these can not applied here. Thx.

Comment: Copy elision is not applicable here, as copy elision was introduced for situations where you are effectively "moving" the value (the original value can no longer be accessed - this is true both for copy initialization and return value). In case of lambda you can access the captured value both in the lambda and in the original context, therefore it is a true copy.